# Xcode8を使ったSwift3のプロジェクトをコピーする最新の方法を教えてください

Tags: swift3, xcode8

プロジェクトを複製する方法を検索すると
[このサイト](http://kubou.net/archives/325)に行き着きますが、
全くコピーできません。

具体的には
　２項でIdentity and Type > NameをRenameしたとき、スナップショットも促されませんし、代わりにworking copy xxxx has uncommitted changed Xcode...という警告が出ます。
　４項ではIdentity and Type > Locationにあるフォルダアイコンをクリックとありますが、アイコンが薄いグレーになっており、クリックもできませんし、Renameしなくても新しくなったディレクトリになっています。
　もちろん.pchファイルも参照できません。

ちなみに４項の時点でwarningも６つ出ており、もちろんbuildもできません。

Comment: 上記の記事は「古いXcode(6かそれ以前)を使用」「複製ではなく(複製後の)プロジェクト名のリネーム方法を示すもの」「Objective-Cのプロジェクト」「gitなどのリポジトリ管理が行われていない」と言う大前提のもとに書かれた内容が、その前提を一切明示しないまま公開されている形です。(正直、自分が何かの回答を書くなら、この記事は元ネタにはしないでしょう…。)あなたの場合、「Xcode8を使用」「Swiftを使用」と言うことで、大前提4つのうち2つが成り立たないことが明らかなのですが、working copy xxxx has uncommitted changesという警告が出るのであれば、リポジトリ管理が行われているので、そちらも該当の記事にはあてはまらないと言うことになります。残る大前提の1点、「プロジェク名のリネーム」はどうしても必要でしょうか?

Comment: swift3のプロジェクトのバックアップが取れれば、どんな方法でも構いません。ただ、わりと膨大なコードでエラーが排出された後、該当のエラーをしたコードを削除してもエラーが治らないなど（私の無知が問題なのでしょうが）のことがあり、１から別プロジェクトとしてコードや書き直す

Comment: １から別プロジェクトとしてコードやIBを書き直すということを繰り返さなければならなかったので、バックアップをとり、エラーを吐く前の状況を保存しておきたいと思った次第です。複製し、１つがだめになったときに、複製した方でプロジェクトを書き直せればなんでも構いません。

Comment: 主にバックアップ目的のコピーということであれば、フォルダー全体(.xcodeprojを含んでいるフォルダー)を丸ごとどこかにコピーするというのが基本です。リネームをするとリンク先記事にあるような面倒な操作の多くをXcode8/Swift用に自分で適切に読み替えて実行しないといけなくなります。コピー後、.xcodeprojファイルもその(同階層内の)隣のプロジェクト名フォルダーもリネームしない方がいいでしょう。(丸ごとコピー対象の一番外側のフォルダーはリネームして構いません。)プロジェクトの状態によっては丸ごとコピーだけではうまくビルドできない場合もあるのですが、とりあえず丸ごとコピー(一番外側以外はリネームしない)で作ったプロジェクトをビルドしてみて(もちろんコピー元のプロジェクトは一旦ビルドできる状態にしてからコピーしてもらわないとダメですが)、うまくいかない部分が出れば、改めてご質問内容の方にご記載ください。文章だけではわかりにくいという部分があれば、少々不完全になりますが、回答欄にもう少しわかりやすくご説明しますので、お知らせください。

Comment: 単純に別場所にコピーということでも、私としては問題はありません。実機でテストするときには一度当該アプリを削除して改めてインストールするなどで対処できそうなので、とりあえずはバックアップフォルダを作りたいと思います。大変ありがとうございました。